# redirect to another link after page tab added

Tags: php, facebook

Okay so I've setup an app which works fine but there's one problem when people add tab to their pages they went to page which show "true" it means page is added successful but i want to redirect them to their page or any other link after page tab added successfully.

```
<?php
session_start();
$facebook=$_SESSION['facebook'];
include("facebook/src/facebook.php");
$facebook=new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '197786760292550',
      'secret' => 'e284332964b213066d3b247e1eb4b4a0',
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }


//Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.

    if ($user) { 

    if(isset($_POST['page']))
    {
    $page=$_POST['page'];
    $explodepage=explode("with",$page);
    $acctoken=$explodepage[1];
    $pgid=$explodepage[0];
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$pgid."/tabs?app_id=197786760292550&access_token=".$acctoken."&method=post";
    ?>
    <script>
window.top.location="<?php echo $url?>";
</script>
    <?php }
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$user."/accounts?access_token=".$access_token;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: graph.facebook.com'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$input=json_decode($output);
$data=$input->data;
$count=count($data)-1; 
?> <form action="" method="post">
<?php for($x=1; $x<=$count; $x++)
{
    $pdata[$x]=$data[$x];
    $pname[$x]=$pdata[$x]->name;
    $ptoken[$x]=$pdata[$x]->access_token;
    $pid[$x]=$pdata[$x]->id; ?>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $pid[$x]; ?>/picture"/>
    <?php echo $pname[$x]."<input type='radio' name='page' value='".$pid[$x]."with".$ptoken[$x]."' /><br>";
} echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'></form>"; } else {
     $app=197786760292550;
$appsecret="e284332964b213066d3b247e1eb4b4a0";
$url="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?";
$redirect="http://luutaa.co.in/fb_close/access_token.php";
$scope="manage_pages,publish_stream";
$x=$url."client_id=".$app."&redirect_uri=".$redirect."&scope=".$scope;
?>
<script>
window.top.location = "<?php echo $x?>";
</script>
   <?php }
?>
```

How can i use redirect to this page which is not mine **graph.facebook.com/255826047791900/…*******&method=post*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $x . "'</script>");
```

Comment: Its still showing that page with if you know any another way of coding which doesn't create issues like it then tell me i'll try that also.

Comment: did you try with 

<?php echo("<script> window.location.href='" . $x . "'</script>"); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 'header'?

```
<?php
header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

Comment: How can i use header to this page which is not mine https://graph.facebook.com/255826047791900/tabs?app_id=197786760292550&access_token=********&method=post